# How to log "catched" exceptions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

When [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) handles uncaught exceptions it prints a nice info of the uncaught exception.How can I do the same on "catched exceptions"?

```
if (err) {
 // winston. log the catched exception
}
```

I checked the source and there seems to be a [`logException` method](https://github.com/flatiron/winston/blob/master/lib/winston/transports/transport.js#L105-L121) but I don't know how I could use it.

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console({handleExceptions: true})]
})
var err = new Error('test error.')
logger.logException(err.message) //no method 'logException'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [logform](https://github.com/winstonjs/logform#errors):

```
const { format } = require('logform');
const { errors } = format;

const errorsFormat = errors({ stack: true })

const info = errorsFormat.transform(new Error('Oh no!'));

console.log(info);
// Error: Oh no!
//     at repl:1:13
//     at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
//     at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:240:29)
//     at bound (domain.js:301:14)
//     at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
//     at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:468:10)
//     at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
//     at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
//     at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
//     at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
```

Or use winston.format.errors({ stack: true }):

```
import winston from 'winston';

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
    winston.format.json(),
    winston.format.prettyPrint(),
  ),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'log/combined.log',
      options: { flags: 'w' },
    }),
  ],
});

export default logger;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can emit catched exception back to process, error will by catched by winston.Logger.  Example:

```
process.emit('uncaughtException', err);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var winston = require('winston');
var err = new Error('test error.');
winston.error(winston.exception.getAllInfo(err));
```

Comment: Maybe this is from an old version of winston, but there is no such API. https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#user-content-exceptions--exception-handling => winston.exception has been removed. Use:
const exception = winston.ExceptionHandler();

Answer (score 0):

`logException` is a method of `Transport`, not of the `Logger` class. What you need is a `error` method:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console({handleExceptions: true})]
})
var err = new Error('test error.');
logger.error(err.message);
```

https://github.com/flatiron/winston#using-logging-levels